# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in React Router component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, syntax-error

I'm encountering a syntax error when working with a React Router component, and I'm unsure how to resolve it. The error message I'm receiving is SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.

I'm using React Router, React Redux, and Redux Toolkit in my React application compiled via Vite. The error seems to be related to the usage of the Route component and the JSX syntax.

Here's the relevant code in my application:

App.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { AuthRoute } from "./util/route_util";
import "./App.css";
import "./scss/02_nav/nav.scss";
import NavBar from "./components/nav/navbar";
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Splash from "./components/splash/splash_page";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <AuthRoute exact path="/" component={Splash} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

RouteUtil.js:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.session.isAuthenticated);
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        !loggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/profile",
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

AuthRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
};

export { AuthRoute };
```

[image: Picture of Error in Source Tab]The error occurs when I try to use the AuthRoute component in my App.js file. I set up the component to be responsible for rendering different routes based on the authentication status of the user. But, when I include the AuthRoute component and define the routes within the Switch component, the syntax error occurs.

I have confirmed that I have imported the necessary dependencies correctly and ensured that the versions of React Router, React Redux, and Redux Toolkit are compatible.

I've tried different variations of the code, including changing the JSX syntax and rearranging the code structure, but the error is still there.

Any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this syntax error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Does this actually cause an error when running the app or do you only see it in your editor (VSCode)?

Comment: I get no such syntax error with this exact code

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the error occurs when JSX syntax is used within a js file, you can try to rename js file to jsx or update your code to be Javascript.